# Spacing between borders in a list

Tags: css

i need the borders of my list to appear like this on the screen, Im not able to put the white spacing between the border-bottom and the border-right.

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/w1n72hkx/3/

HTML:

```
<div>
<ul class="barraDatosSociales">
<li>Valoración 4,6 (267 votos)</li>
<li>108 comentarios</li>
<li>716 veces compartido</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.barraDatosSociales {
  border: solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  margin-right: 3%;
  border-color: DarkTurquoise;
}
.barraDatosSociales li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
.barraDatosSociales li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: DarkTurquoise;
}
.barraDatosSociales li:not(:first-child) {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Here i attach an image of how it should look like:
[image: Final result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply a bottom and top margin to your `li` elements and set their `display` to `inline-block` in order to make the margin matter.

```css
.barraDatosSociales {
  border: solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  margin-right: 3%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-color: DarkTurquoise;
}

.barraDatosSociales li {
  padding-right: 5px;
  
  /*Here' what changed*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0;

  border-collapse: separate;
}

.barraDatosSociales li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: DarkTurquoise;
}

.barraDatosSociales li:not(:first-child) {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul class="barraDatosSociales">
        <li>Valoración 4,6 (267 votos)</li>
        <li>108 comentarios</li>
        <li>716 veces compartido</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to separate the internal borders:
you could move up list-items with a negative `top` value, e.g.

```
.barraDatosSociales li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
```

or you could add a `padding-bottom` to the outer container

```
.barraDatosSociales {
  border: solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  margin-right: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-color: DarkTurquoise;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a little modification in the css for the list-items.

Inline elements do not accept top/bottom padding and margins. So try using `display: inline-block`

```
.barraDatosSociales li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```